# File upload on s3 fail getting the com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException Exception

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

I am using the **`amazonaws`** S3 for uploading the media file getting the following error like below:-

> E/UploadTask: Failed to upload: 15 due to Forbidden **(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null)**
>   E/Exeception: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden **(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null)**, S3 Extended Request ID: null
>    E/percentage: 100  15
>    E/statechange: FAILED

I have used the following code for it , please check it once.

```
 CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            context, NetworkTask.BASE_AWS_KEY, Regions.US_EAST_1);// Region

   AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

    s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

    transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, context);
        TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
                "MY-BUCKET-NAME"     /* The bucket to upload to */
                , fileUploadName, /* The key for the uploaded object */
                fileToUpload       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        );

        transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                Log.e("statechange", state + "");

                if (String.valueOf(state).equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETED")) {
                    fileUploadInterface.getUploadFileUrl(String.valueOf(s3.getUrl("zargow.vcard.image", fileUploadName)), service_id);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
                Log.e("percentage", percentage + "" + "  " + id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Exeception", ex.toString());
            }

        });
```

**4 out of 5 times i am getting above error and one time getting the success response.**

I have used the following gradle for it,please check it once

```
 compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.13') {
        exclude module: 'gson'
    }
```

I have visited the following site before posting the question but did not get any expected result.Please check the links 
[1. First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328376/how-to-resolve-amazons3exception-forbidden-service-amazon-s3-status-code-40) 
[2. Second link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/53) 
[3. Third link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1026) 
[4. Forth link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218538/com-amazonaws-services-s3-model-amazons3exception-forbidden-service-amazon-s3) 
[5. Fifth link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798926/com-amazonaws-services-s3-model-amazons3exception-access-denied)

Please check it once, and let me know what did i wrong on the code. Please help me to short out from this problem

Comment: Why are you using CognitoCachingCredentials? Are you moving custom data back and forth or a 3rd party Auth tool like Google? Or just using S3 for media storage?

Comment: No I am just want to upload media file to s3 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well this took me a ton of time to get right, but I'm going to share it with you ;). Below is a CognitoHelper class I wrote to manage using the credentials needed for Authentication as well as S3 information. I don't know your full app or what you are using, so I'm just giving you the full thing.

```
    import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoDevice;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserAttributes;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserDetails;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserSession;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.continuations.AuthenticationContinuation;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.continuations.AuthenticationDetails;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.continuations.ChallengeContinuation;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.continuations.ForgotPasswordContinuation;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.continuations.MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.handlers.AuthenticationHandler;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.handlers.ForgotPasswordHandler;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.handlers.GenericHandler;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.handlers.GetDetailsHandler;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.handlers.UpdateAttributesHandler;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.handlers.VerificationHandler;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by App Studio 35 on 7/27/17.
 */
public class CognitoManager {

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CONSTANTS
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static class S3BucketInfo {
        public static final String DEV_BUCKET_NAME = "<YOUR-PHOTOS-STAGING-BUCKET>";

        public static final String PRD_BUCKET_NAME = "<YOUR-PHOTOS-PROD-BUCKET>";

    }
    public static class CognitoProviderInfo {
        public static final Regions DEV_REGION = Regions.US_EAST_1;

        public static final Regions PRD_REGION = Regions.US_EAST_1;

    }
    public static class S3ClientInfo {
        public static final String PRD_CLIENT_ACCESS_KEY = "<YOUR-CLIENT-ACCESS-KEY>";
        public static final String PRD_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY = "<YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET-KEY>";

    }
    public static class CognitoUserPoolInfo {
        public static final String DEV_USER_POOL_ID = "us-east-1_<YOUR-LETTERS>"; //DON'T USE EAST IF YOU ARE NOT EAST
        public static final String DEV_APP_PROVIDER_CLIENT_ID = "<YOUR-APP-STAGE-PROVIDER-CLIENT-ID-FOR-ANDROID>";
        public static final String DEV_APP_PROVIDER_CLIENT_SECRET = "<YOUR-APP-STAGE-PROVIDER-CLIENT-SECRET-FOR-ANDROID-PROVIDER>";

        public static final String PRD_USER_POOL_ID = "us-east-1_<YOUR LETTERS>"; //DON'T USE EAST IF YOU ARE NOT EAST
        public static final String PRD_APP_PROVIDER_CLIENT_ID = "<YOUR-APP-PROD-PROVIDER-CLIENT-ID-FOR-ANDROID>";
        public static final String PRD_APP_PROVIDER_CLIENT_SECRET = "<YOUR-APP-PROD-PROVIDER-CLIENT-ID-FOR-ANDROID>";

    }


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // MEMBERS
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static final String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + CognitoManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private static CognitoManager mInstance;
    private static CognitoUserPool mUserPool;
    private static String mUser;
    private static boolean mIsEmailVerified;
    private static boolean mIsPhoneVerified;
    private static CognitoUserSession mCurrentUserSession;


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // PROPERTIES
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static String getUserPoolID(){
        switch (AMEnvironment.getCurrentEnvironment()){
            case DEV:
            case QA:
            case STG:
                return CognitoUserPoolInfo.DEV_USER_POOL_ID;

            case PRD:
            default:
                return CognitoUserPoolInfo.PRD_USER_POOL_ID;

        }

    }
    public static String getClientID(){
        switch (AMEnvironment.getCurrentEnvironment()){
            case DEV:
            case QA:
            case STG:
                return CognitoUserPoolInfo.DEV_APP_PROVIDER_CLIENT_ID;

            case PRD:
            default:
                return CognitoUserPoolInfo.PRD_APP_PROVIDER_CLIENT_ID;

        }

    }
    public static String getClientSecret(){
        switch (AMEnvironment.getCurrentEnvironment()){
            case DEV:
            case QA:
            case STG:
                return CognitoUserPoolInfo.DEV_APP_PROVIDER_CLIENT_SECRET;

            case PRD:
            default:
                return CognitoUserPoolInfo.PRD_APP_PROVIDER_CLIENT_SECRET;

        }

    }
    public static String getS3ClientID(){
        switch (AMEnvironment.getCurrentEnvironment()){
            case DEV:
            case QA:
            case STG:
            case PRD:
            default:
                return S3ClientInfo.PRD_CLIENT_ACCESS_KEY;

        }

    }
    public static String getS3ClientSecret(){
        switch (AMEnvironment.getCurrentEnvironment()){
            case DEV:
            case QA:
            case STG:
            case PRD:
            default:
                return S3ClientInfo.PRD_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY;

        }

    }
    public static String getS3BucketName(){
        switch (AMEnvironment.getCurrentEnvironment()){
            case DEV:
            case QA:
            case STG:
                return S3BucketInfo.DEV_BUCKET_NAME;

            case PRD:
            default:
                return S3BucketInfo.PRD_BUCKET_NAME;

        }
    }
    public static Regions getCognitoRegion(){
        switch (AMEnvironment.getCurrentEnvironment()){
            case DEV:
            case QA:
            case STG:
                return CognitoProviderInfo.DEV_REGION;

            case PRD:
            default:
                return CognitoProviderInfo.PRD_REGION;

        }

    }
    public static void setUser(String user){
        mUser = user;
    }
    public static String getUser(){
        return mUser;
    }
    public static CognitoUserPool getUserPool(){
        return mUserPool;

    }
    public static CognitoUserSession getCurrentUserSession(){
        return mCurrentUserSession;

    }
    public static void setCurrentUserSession(CognitoUserSession session){
        mCurrentUserSession = session;

    }


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // INIT
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void init(Context context) {
        if (mInstance != null && mUserPool != null) {
            return;

        }

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CognitoManager();

        }

        if (mUserPool == null) {
            // Create a user pool with default ClientConfiguration
            mUserPool = new CognitoUserPool(context, getUserPoolID(), getClientID(), getClientSecret(), getCognitoRegion());

        }

    }


    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // EXTERNAL METHODS
    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void signInUser(final String user, final String password, final AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler){
        setUser(user);
        getUserPool().getUser(user).getSessionInBackground(new AuthenticationHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final CognitoUserSession userSession, final CognitoDevice newDevice) {
                setCurrentUserSession(userSession);
                rememberTrustedDevice(newDevice);
                getUserDetails(new GetDetailsHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {
                        try{
                            mIsEmailVerified = Boolean.parseBoolean(cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes().get(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.IS_EMAIL_VALIDATED_ATTRIBUTE));//"email_verified" is the string
                            //mIsPhoneVerified = Boolean.parseBoolean(cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes().get(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.IS_EMAIL_VALIDATED_ATTRIBUTE));

                        }catch (Exception ex){


                        }

                        authenticationHandler.onSuccess(userSession, newDevice);

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                        authenticationHandler.onSuccess(userSession, newDevice);

                    }
                });

            }
            @Override
            public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String UserId) {
                Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
                AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(user, password, null);
                authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);
                authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
                authenticationHandler.getAuthenticationDetails(authenticationContinuation, UserId);

            }
            @Override
            public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {
                authenticationHandler.getMFACode(continuation);

            }
            @Override
            public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {
                authenticationHandler.authenticationChallenge(continuation);
                //TODO implement "new_password_required" or "phone_needs_verified" or "email_needs_verified" instead of passing back lazily use correct callbacks of phone or password etc.. for cleanliness

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                authenticationHandler.onFailure(exception);

            }

        });

    }
    public static void signOutCurrentUser(){
        if(getUserPool().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            getUserPool().getCurrentUser().signOut();

        }

    }
    public static void rememberTrustedDevice(CognitoDevice newDevice){
        if(newDevice != null) {
            newDevice.rememberThisDeviceInBackground(new GenericHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    //not really sure if we need to do anything with this info or not just yet

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                    //Faled to save device

                }

            });

        }

    }
    public static void refreshToken(final GenericHandler genericHandler){ //called from background thread to keep session alive
        if(getUserPool() == null || getUserPool().getCurrentUser() == null || getUserPool().getCurrentUser().getUserId() == null){
            genericHandler.onFailure(new Exception("Invalid User Token"));

        }else{
            getUserPool().getCurrentUser().getSessionInBackground(new AuthenticationHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession userSession, CognitoDevice newDevice) {
                    setCurrentUserSession(userSession);
                    rememberTrustedDevice(newDevice);
                    getUserDetails(new GetDetailsHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {
                            try{
                                mIsEmailVerified = Boolean.parseBoolean(cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes().get(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.IS_EMAIL_VALIDATED_ATTRIBUTE));
                                //mIsPhoneVerified = Boolean.parseBoolean(cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes().get(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.IS_PHONE_VALIDATED_ATTRIBUTE)); //not used in my current app

                            }catch (Exception ex){


                            }

                            genericHandler.onSuccess();

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                            genericHandler.onSuccess();
                        }
                    });

                }
                @Override
                public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String UserId) {
                    genericHandler.onFailure(new Exception("Invalid User Token"));

                }
                @Override
                public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {
                    genericHandler.onFailure(new Exception("Invalid User Token"));

                }
                @Override
                public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {
                    genericHandler.onFailure(new Exception("Invalid User Token"));

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                    genericHandler.onFailure(new Exception("Invalid User Token"));

                }

            });

        }

    }
    /**
     * Used to update cached booleans for isEmailVerified or isPhoneVerified
     */
    public static void phoneOrEmailChanged(){
        if(getUserPool().getCurrentUser() == null){
            return;

        }

        getUserDetails(new GetDetailsHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {
                try{
                    mIsEmailVerified = Boolean.parseBoolean(cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes().get(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.IS_EMAIL_VALIDATED_ATTRIBUTE));
                    //mIsPhoneVerified = Boolean.parseBoolean(cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes().get(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.IS_PHONE_VALIDATED_ATTRIBUTE)); //"phone_number" is string, but not used in my current app

                }catch (Exception ex){


                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {

            }

        });

    }
    public static boolean isPhoneVerified(){
        return true; //for now we are not verifying phone
        //return mIsPhoneVerified;
    }
    public static boolean isEmailVerified(){
        return mIsEmailVerified;
    }
    public static void getUserDetails(GetDetailsHandler handler){
        getUserPool().getCurrentUser().getDetailsInBackground(handler);

    }
    public static void updatePhoneNumber(String phone, final GenericHandler handler){
        CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
        userAttributes.addAttribute(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.PHONE_ATTRIBUTE, PhoneNumberHelper.getStrippedNumberWithCountryCode(phone));

        CognitoManager.getUserPool().getUser(CognitoManager.getUserPool().getCurrentUser().getUserId()).updateAttributesInBackground(userAttributes, new UpdateAttributesHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails> attributesVerificationList) {
                handler.onSuccess();

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                handler.onFailure(exception);

            }

        });
    }
    public static void updateEmail(String email, final GenericHandler handler){
        CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
        userAttributes.addAttribute(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.EMAIL_ATTRIBUTE, email);
        CognitoManager.getUserPool().getUser(CognitoManager.getUserPool().getCurrentUser().getUserId()).updateAttributesInBackground(userAttributes, new UpdateAttributesHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails> attributesVerificationList) {
                handler.onSuccess();

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                handler.onFailure(exception);
            }

        });

    }
    public static void updatePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword, final GenericHandler handler){
        getUserPool().getUser().changePasswordInBackground(oldPassword, newPassword, new GenericHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                handler.onSuccess();

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                handler.onFailure(exception);
            }

        });
    }
    public static void forgotPassword(String email, final ForgotPasswordHandler handler){
        getUserPool().getUser(email).forgotPasswordInBackground(new ForgotPasswordHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                handler.onSuccess();
            }
            @Override
            public void getResetCode(ForgotPasswordContinuation continuation) {
                handler.getResetCode(continuation);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                handler.onFailure(exception);

            }

        });
    }
    public static void sendVerificationEmail(final VerificationHandler handler){
        getUserPool().getCurrentUser().getAttributeVerificationCodeInBackground(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.PHONE_ATTRIBUTE, new VerificationHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails verificationCodeDeliveryMedium) {
                handler.onSuccess(verificationCodeDeliveryMedium);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                handler.onFailure(exception);

            }

        });

    }
    public static void sendVerificationText(final VerificationHandler handler){
        getUserPool().getCurrentUser().getAttributeVerificationCodeInBackground(Globals.CUSTOM_USER_ATTRIBUTES.PHONE_ATTRIBUTE, new VerificationHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails verificationCodeDeliveryMedium) {
                handler.onSuccess(verificationCodeDeliveryMedium);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                handler.onFailure(exception);

            }

        });

    }
    public static void verifyAttributesInBackground(String attribute, String code, final GenericHandler handler){
        CognitoManager.getUserPool().getCurrentUser().verifyAttributeInBackground(attribute, code, new GenericHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                handler.onSuccess();

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                handler.onFailure(exception);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Next up how to use the S3 piece of it:

```
private void uploadImageToS3(String filePath){
        final File newImageFile = new File(filePath);
        showProgressDialog(TAG, getString(R.string.loading_please_wait));

        //For auth route
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(CognitoManager.getS3ClientID(), CognitoManager.getS3ClientSecret());

        AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, this);
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(CognitoManager.getS3BucketName(), newImageFile.getName(), newImageFile);
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if(state.compareTo(TransferState.COMPLETED) == 0){
                String imgURLOfUploadComplete = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/" + CognitoManager.getS3BucketName() + "/" + newImageFile.getName();
                hideProgressDialog(TAG);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_IMAGE_URL, imgURLOfUploadComplete);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                if(newImageFile.exists()){
                    newImageFile.delete();

                }
                finish();

            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            if(bytesTotal != 0) {
                //For viewing progress
                int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            A35Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.error_uploading_s3_part1) + id + getString(R.string.error_uploading_s3_part2) + ex.getMessage());
            hideProgressDialog(TAG);
            showDialogMessage(getString(error), getString(R.string.error_failed_create_image_alert_id) + error);

        }

    });

}
```

and that's it. Now you have a fully functioning example of Cognito and S3, you just have to put in your keys and make sure you setup your Android Provider for your app in S3 if you are using that piece, but if you are just using the S3 piece with id and secret you probably don't need the CognitoHelper stuff, just use your secret and id and bucket names for your environment and be done. I used the same security group and id/secret for prd and stage just separated by buckets, but you can do whatever you want with that.

Comment: Thanks for urs valuable effort..I will check it on Monday .+1 ur effort

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any issues.